# How to integrate new payment gateways with django-payments?

Tags: python, django, open-source, payment-gateway, payment

I want to integrate payments for a personal Django project that I'm working on.

[Saleor](https://github.com/mirumee/saleor) uses [django-payments](https://github.com/mirumee/django-payments) for payment processing. Unfortunately, most of them don't work here in India. Cybersource does work but their transaction fees are a bit higher compared to the payment gateways from India.

I'd like to implement something like [Razorpay](https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-python) or [Instamojo](https://github.com/Instamojo/instamojo-py) into django-payments such that I don't end up breaking Saleor in any way but I don't have the faintest idea on how to start.

I clone the package and then what? I was suggested to use the "dummy" as reference to implement the functionality but I've got no idea on how to test if it even works.

How should I go about that? I don't see any contributing guidelines as well. I don't mind contributing back to the repo as well. I just want someone to point me in the right direction and I will take it forward from there. Thank you!

Comment: it's my concern too, did you find anything helpful yet?

Comment: @MahdiRashidi sadly, no. I haven't found a solution to this yet. I've been poking around the repo a bit but I haven't gotten far. Have you found anything worthwhile?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the [Django-payments](https://django-payments.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) module by adding to it like this. After installing Saleor and its dependencies with `pip install -r requirements.txt` with a virtual environment, go to the environment folder and look in `lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/payments`.

In there, you will find directories of all the integrated providers. They look like this:

```
stripe/
├── forms.py
├── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── ...
├── test_stripe.py
└── widgets.py
```

Use this as a guide to integrate the Razorpay or Instamojo modules. For example, the stripe integration uses stripe's python module whereas sofort simply uses http requests. The main `Provider` class is inside the `__init__.py` file. Once you've added the integrations, change your `settings.py` in `saleor/` to put your new methods as checkout options.

This is of course a messy way to add to a module. Rather clone Django-payments directly and make your changes, then install it in your Saleor project.